# Jelastic manifest prepopulation of list values

Tags: manifest, populate, jelastic

I am creating a deploy for OpenMage e-commerce here: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/openmage-cluster

In the creation settings dialog, I want to prepopulate the TIMEZONE, LOCALES and CURRENCY from a list generated by a PHP script.

Relevant parts are here:

- Generated prepopulate data: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/openmage-cluster/blob/main/settings/populate.txt
- Script I use to make that: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/openmage-cluster/blob/main/scripts/settings_generate.php
- and then the manifest: https://github.com/ProxiBlue/openmage-cluster/blob/main/manifest.jps#L31

I pinged Jelastic support and they gave me this format to use to make the prepopulate:

```
{ "result": 0, "data": { "yourSettingName1": "value1", "yourSettingName2": "value2" } }
```

however, that only seems to allow population of single value fields, so I end up with OBJECTS in the list selection:

[image]

There must obviously be a different format for this, but their docs don;t show what it should be.

Anyone can help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There must obviously be a different format for this, but their docs don't show what it should be.

Option "prepopulate" in JPS manifests can be used only to fill simple "Key:Value" pairs, and does not support a list of values.

Instead, for enabling more dynamic changes in prepopulated values, we suggest you use onBeforeInit event.

Example of OpenMage Cluster manifest with it you can find in the link below:
https://gist.github.com/SlavaKatiukha/6babcefcae557813fe11f994bc13599d#file-openmage-cluster-settings-example-yaml-L61-L69